# Is it possible to trigger "show more" text only on his own div parent section?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div sections which are in the same page and all have the "show more text" and "show less text" function.

I have written the correct function to expand and shrink the text.
But having more than one section the problem is that the click function trigger all my sections and not only the section (DIV) where I click.

I want to trigger the function only on his DIV and not in all the page, and I don't want to use unique id's or unique classes for my section because I have a lot of this sections to use in my pages.

Is there a way to automatically order the function to activate only within its div?

Thanks!

```js
$('.show-more').click(function() {
    if($('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '80px'){
        $('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '80px'}, 200);
        $(this).text('MORE');

    }else{
        $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = $('.show-more-snippet').height();
        $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'80px'});
        $('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        $(this).text('LESS');
    }
});
```

```css
.show-more-snippet {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-persona{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-persona">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">     
        <h5>John Doe</h5>

    <p class="show-more-snippet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at lectus at risus pretium luctus. Vivamus vitae neque urna. Aliquam et felis a enim commodo fringilla. Quisque sed blandit diam. Vestibulum sem ex, semper non velit at, dictum pharetra lorem. Phasellus elementum condimentum urna, vel fringilla nunc auctor quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus laoreet, ipsum a congue eleifend, sem diam aliquam lectus, eget laoreet lacus lorem sit amet justo.

Pellentesque at lorem vitae lacus pretium laoreet. Praesent urna mauris, elementum at vehicula vel, interdum vel tellus. Mauris efficitur scelerisque risus, eget ornare velit pretium et. Praesent euismod metus quis mollis tristique. Suspendisse ultricies sed nunc id pulvinar. Maecenas sagittis ipsum at ipsum semper vulputate. Vestibulum gravida auctor ligula, sed fermentum ipsum. Fusce commodo luctus porttitor. Sed eu enim quis nisl aliquam fringilla. Phasellus interdum ex in lorem fringilla, ac rhoncus velit aliquet.</p> 

          <p class="show-more">MORE</p>  
        </div>


<div class="container-persona">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">     
        <h5>John Doe</h5>

    <p class="show-more-snippet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at lectus at risus pretium luctus. Vivamus vitae neque urna. Aliquam et felis a enim commodo fringilla. Quisque sed blandit diam. Vestibulum sem ex, semper non velit at, dictum pharetra lorem. Phasellus elementum condimentum urna, vel fringilla nunc auctor quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus laoreet, ipsum a congue eleifend, sem diam aliquam lectus, eget laoreet lacus lorem sit amet justo.

Pellentesque at lorem vitae lacus pretium laoreet. Praesent urna mauris, elementum at vehicula vel, interdum vel tellus. Mauris efficitur scelerisque risus, eget ornare velit pretium et. Praesent euismod metus quis mollis tristique. Suspendisse ultricies sed nunc id pulvinar. Maecenas sagittis ipsum at ipsum semper vulputate. Vestibulum gravida auctor ligula, sed fermentum ipsum. Fusce commodo luctus porttitor. Sed eu enim quis nisl aliquam fringilla. Phasellus interdum ex in lorem fringilla, ac rhoncus velit aliquet.</p> 

          <p class="show-more">MORE</p>  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.prev` function

Change your Jquery code to this code

```
$('.show-more').click(function() {
    if($(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css('height') != '80px'){
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: '80px'}, 200);
        $(this).text('MORE');

    }else{
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').height();
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'80px'});
        $(this).prev('.show-more-snippet').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        $(this).text('LESS');
    }
});
```